# Lotus Notes Java API. Mail forwarding

Tags: java, email, lotus-notes

I would like to forward emails from my Lotus Notes inbox to my gmail account.

Lotus Notes rules and agents are disabled on our server, so I developed external application for that.
I am using document.send method and mail successfully arrives to my gmail box.
The only problem is that often the email also duplicated in my Lotus Notes inbox.
I just found that the reason of that is "CC" and "BCC" fields, which I don't clean up,
however, I am looking for the way to forward email as it is - which means keep original CC and BCC and TO fields - exactly on the same way as it is done by forwarding agent.

I am using "IBM Notes 9" on Windows 7 64 bit.

I've prepared a code sample that demonstrates what I am doing.

```
package com.example;

import lotus.domino.*;

public class TestMailForwarder {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NotesException {
        NotesThread.sinitThread();
        try {
            Session notesSession = NotesFactory.createSession(
                    (String) null, (String) null, Consts.NOTES_PASSWORD);
            DbDirectory dir = notesSession.getDbDirectory(Consts.NOTES_SERVER);
            Database mailDb = dir.openDatabaseByReplicaID(Consts.MAILDB_REPLICA_ID);
            forwardAllEmails(mailDb);
        } finally {
            NotesThread.stermThread();
        }
    }

    private static void forwardAllEmails(Database mailDb) throws NotesException {
        View inbox = mailDb.getView("$Inbox");
        //noinspection LoopStatementThatDoesntLoop
        for (Document document = inbox.getFirstDocument(); 
                 null != document; 
                 document = inbox.getNextDocument(document)) {
            document.send(Consts.GMAIL_ADDRESS);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are unable to mail forward in the client, your admin may have intentionally disabled it. So coding a workaround may violate your company policy. Check with your admin.

Comment: You can't do a transparent forward with code running at the client level. Pure SMTP systems do it by preserving the RFC-822 header content while altering the RFC-821 RCPT TO data.  Domino does not give client-level code independent control over these. It just uses the SendTo, CopyTo, and BlindCopyTo items. (There are some tricks that mail management and archiving vendors play in order to do things like this, but they require special changes to the Domino server's router configuration, and software on the other end as well.

Comment: Thank you Richard. If you would put it as an answer, I would mark it as complete answer, indeed. Could I implement it with Java Mail API, so I will forward directly to gmail without Notes Server?

Comment: Done! And I addressed the Java Mail API question there as well. :-)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/758513/mail-forwarding-with-javamail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found a ready solution: [AWESYNC.MAIL](http://www.awesync.com/products/awesync.mail).
It is a commercial software but it does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to send the messages to your GMail, why not upload them using Gmail's IMAP interface. You would require to get the message as MIME content - which probably they are already for external incoming eMails and then push them to GMail.
I don't have a ready code sample, just one for the opposite [pulling GMail into Notes](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-9FCMHJ?Open), but you should be able to use that as a starting point.

A code sample for the MIME conversion is in an [IBM Technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21230698).

Hope that helps

Comment: and yes - your intention probably violates corporate guidelines, to the probability of instant termination. Why not... create a local web server accessing your mailbox and make your own little mail UI. Or you could after getting the MIME move it into a Thunderbird client

Comment: thanks. 
1. my local webserver won't be accessible from outside of the office
2. i use gmail because it's advanced search capabilities. lotus notes search is just awful, I never manage to find anything
3. gmail is kind of external backup

Comment: The practical question is: given I send directly yo gmail, do you know how can I setup proper forwarding which keeps original "from, to, cc, bcc" in  RFC-822 header, as explained by Richard in comment to my question?

Comment: Switch on your full text index and Notes is as capable as the gmail crawler. In R9 you can even search mail and archive in one go.

Comment: For all practical purposes you are better off going down the IMAP route. For the header preservation you need to talk directly to the gmail SMTP - and then it just might start routing messages

Comment: BTW: I agree with @stwissel and Simon. Lotus Notes has had excellent full text search capabilities for a long time. It was way ahead of everything else on the market until gmail came along.  Unfortunately, some admins don't don't allow it, or sometimes it's just a matter of learning how to turn it on. At a minimum, you should be able to make a local replica of your mail and turn on full text indexing there. If you need more information about this, just ask us. Writing code that probably violates company security policy is not a good workaround for something that shouldn't even be a problem!

Comment: Thank you for clear answers. I would be glad to ask questions about Lotus Notes, I am just not sure this thread is a proper scope for that.

Comment: I do have a a local replica with full search but still I often can't find things that I find in gmail. Also "conversation view" is not working well - sometime I am missing new replies to the emails because they are not highlighted as new.  Search in "conversation view" also doesn't work well.... There is no "redo" option when I compose the email ... and many other obstacles. In addition I often has to read emails abroad, so I don't have access to my local replicate and on server, I don't have all the history because of the 1GB quota limitation.... I can continue for a long - long time :)

Comment: SuperUser is definitely a better place to ask questions about Lotus Notes non-programming functionality than a comment thread on StackOverflow. :-)  In any case, without examples I can't give much advice about search results, I never liked the conversations view and I don't really like what gmail does with conversations either (and it's not perfect in capturing all messages, too), the redo issue is real, and you can block deletions from your local replica so you can have more than 1 GB there (but it seems like you're saying you don't always have that with you and I can't help with that.)

Comment: Suggest to your company to switch to IBM SmartCloud Notes - you get 25G of eMail and the latest version of the Notes client and web access. For other questions open a new question. Software usage typically is asked on superuser a stackoverflow sister site

Answer (score 2):

You can't do a transparent forward with code running at the client level. Pure SMTP systems do it by preserving the RFC-822 header content while altering the RFC-821 RCPT TO data. Domino does not give client-level code independent control over these. It just uses the SendTo, CopyTo, and BlindCopyTo items. (There are some tricks that mail management and archiving vendors play in order to do things like this, but they require special changes to the Domino server's router configuration, and software on the other end as well.

Another way of accomplishing this (in response to the question you asked in your comment) would be to have your Java code make a direct connection to the gmail SMTP servers. I'm not sure how easy it is.  A comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320100/java-mail-to-multiple-recipients) states that the Java Mail API allows you to control the RCPT TO separately from the RFC822 headers, but I've not looked into the specifics other than taking note that there's an SMTPTransport class -- which is where I'd look for anything related to RFC-821 protocol.  The bigger issue is that you will have to take control of converting messages into MIME format. With Notes mail, you may have a mix of Notes rich text and MIME.  Theres a [convertToMIME method](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CONVERTTOMIME_METHOD_JAVA.html) in Notes 8.5.1 and above, but this will only convert the message body. You'll have to deal with any header content separately.  (I'm not really up to speed on Notes 9, but AFAIK even though there is functionality in the client to create a .EML file when you drag a message to the desktop, there's no API there to do that for you.)