# Mail forwarding with javamail

Tags: jakarta-mail, email

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502050/lotus-notes-java-api-mail-forwarding/23523746#23523746) thread, I am trying to implement mail forwarding to gmail with javamail,
however I don't manage to make the email to contain original from and to and cc lines.
Whatever I do, the email appear as it was sent by the user authenticated by the session.
To simplify the request: how to redefine FROM, TO, CC and BCC lines of the email sent to gmail without really sending an email to this addresses.

Something like that:

```
@Test
public void test3() throws Exception {
    SMTPMessage msg = new SMTPMessage(session);
    msg.setSubject("Testing");
    msg.setText("Body of the email");
    // TRYING TO REPLACE "FROM" ADDRES BY from_nobody@nowhere.com
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, Constants.GMAIL_ADDRESS);
    msg.setFrom("from_nobody@nowhere.com");
    msg.setEnvelopeFrom("from_nobody@nowhere.com");
    msg.setSubmitter("from_nobody@nowhere.com");
    msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse("from_nobody@nowhere.com"));
    // BUT IT DOESN"T HELP. 
    // THE USER AUTHENTICATED IN THE SESSION 
    // APPEARS AS THE SENDER OF THE EMAIL IN GMAIL INTERFACE 
    Transport.send(msg);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In general, Gmail won't let you send email from any From address you want.  See [this Gmail help page](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370) for details.

Comment: please read original thread. if mail if forwarded by domino (or any other) server, then it appears with original to,cc and bcc lines. I just want to simulate this behavior.

Comment: Right, Gmail will accept mail sent from another SMTP server that appears to come from an address within the domain of that SMTP server.  That doesn't appear to be what you're doing.  Did you read the link above?

Comment: Yes, I did. However, even when email is sent from different domain (OD) to my mailbox at my domain (MD) and forwarded to gmail by my smpt server, I can see original from address, which belongs to different domain (OD).